# How do I install MinGW on a computer with no internet connection?

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, mingw

I'm learning C/C++, for the learning purpose I will be using netbeans-7.4 installed on my  window-8 system.

How do I install MinGW without internet connection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the MinGW [*HOWTO Install the MinGW (GCC) Compiler Suite*](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW) page, they offer some Manual Installation instructions.  These work without an Internet connection if you can get the installation files to your machine by some other means.

You will need a computer with an Internet connection to download the files for MinGW.  But as long as you can put those files on, say, a USB thumb drive or other media, you should be OK.  Download the files you'll need for your Windows 8 machine on an Internet-connected machine, and then transfer them to your Windows 8 box.  This is what us old-timers sometimes jokingly called "sneakernet."

You will also need a tool like 7-Zip or similar (as noted on the page linked above), to unpack the archives you download.  So, if you don't have that tool, you will also have to download that installer from an Internet connected machine and transfer it to your machine by thumb drive sneakernet as well.

Comment: Cool beans.  Good luck with MinGW and have fun!  I've been using it for years to move my code back and forth between Linux and Windows, and I happen to think it's quite slick.